# 2 sets of Label and editorFor boxs on the same line using css

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

Want to have 2 labels and input fields on same line.

Like this - underline for example- would be box for input:

NAME:________      JOBNO:________

I have this in my view and it is displaying  the label & editfor box on 1 line:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NAME)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NAME)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NAME)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JOBNO)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JOBNO)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JOBNO)
    </div>
```

DO I have to use a table to display the data - used a table  for my DETAIL view but not working so good for the EDIT view.
 it's a crowded form and  a single line down the page just will not do. This seems like it would be a commonly done but can't find an example of how to do it.
Any suggestions or useful how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely possible with CSS.  Here's a really simple solution just using float:

```css
.editor-label, .editor-field {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor-label">
    <label>Field #1</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    <label>Field #2</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="text' />
</div>
```

Using float isn't super ideal - you probably want a more sophisticated layout system.  Take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or other CSS frameworks.

*EDIT*

As per your request, here's a sample using Bootstrap 3's grid system.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Field 1</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Field 2</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I do want it to look professional. THese are forms that were done in Oracle Forms that have been used for almost 20 years  that I'm converting to the web and SQL Server.

Comment: If this was used - would you just add a <br/>  to make it go to the next line - I have approximately 80 fields to display

Comment: I would actually discourage you from using floats and line breaks - this was just a throwaway proof of concept.  If you aren't comfortable with writing the CSS yourself to make something usable and look professional, I strongly encourage you to look at a CSS framework to help you out.  See Bootstrap, Material Design, Foundation, etc....

Comment: Looking for a sample using CSS or maybe Bootstrap  - need to search for Bootstrap instead of CSS  or one of the other frameworks.  See LOTS of samples with single column edit screens.  Any good tutorials out there for  Bootstrap or Foundation?

Comment: @farmer: I edited in a simple example using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Label and input display inline by default so you can just remove your divs.

```html
<label>Field #1</label>
<input type="text" />
<label>Field #2</label>
<input type="text' />
```

Comment: This did not work for me - wish it was that easy. Probable some other css I have set - but not going to bang up my other pages.